# What is the way to add images by the url in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I added image url in img src tag in my angular application and it is not working. `<img class="img-fluid mb-1" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iIwtotpPYKooz7AfsiDEnsoi-WAZBJt1/view">`
Is there any different way to give the source for images?

Comment: You need absolute `src` for images. For example: https://i.imgur.com/Vsp1C8h.jpg

Comment: This is happening because of Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)
here you can read more about it https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768